# How to add some function on Leave Button

Tags: reactjs, browser

Like on click of leave I want that user should get logged out
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `onbeforeunload` and `onload`.

```js
// this event is triggered when user leaves the page
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Changes that you made may not be saved.";
};

// After user presses Leave button this event is triggered then you can invoke logoutUser function
window.onunload = function() {
    logoutUser();
};
```

In react

```js
const handleBeforeUnload = e => {
  return "Changes that you made may not be saved.";
}

const handleUnload = e => {
  logoutUser();
}

// In app component
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
  window.addEventListener("unload", handleUnload);
  
  return () => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
    window.addEventListener("unload", handleUnload);
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Hello, This is not working for me

Comment: Can you please share you code?